# When will students be taken into account?

Tags: discussion, students

As student, I recently asked myself - and other mates did - why Stack Overflow had no special diet adapted to students, more indulgent than with developers. Indeed, we noticed that our questions were frequently downvoted or did not receive enough attention. I don't find it normal that a beginner does not really have the same chance than an experimented developer, as its reputation tends to stay low

Thus, although I perfectly understand that Stack should remain something for "professional developers" and not a MOOC-provider, I think that it should be fine to give a special status to students to avoid them being discouraged to ask questions that could seem obvious.

So I would suggest a scholarship proof from the university or school to avoid derives. It would witness of open-mindness

Comment: There's nothing saying students can't ask questions- It's just that students need to read and follow site rules _the same as anyone else._ What makes you think, aside from downvoted questions, that you and your friends can't ask questions?

Comment: You don't need to be a professional to learn to ask good questions, or learn to reseach for yourself. One of the most *useful* classes I ever had basically went "Ok, this is how you find stuff for yourself.

Downvotes are also a teaching experience *combined* with good advice.

Comment: The issue with these questions is, people just dump their homework on a site and expect people to do it for them, no effort, no reasearch, we should not allow that, it is counter productive for a student to be spoon fed solutions. Of course, if you ask a well written, well reaserched question, that is fine but "PLZ HELP, I AM STUDENT AND DON'T KNOW ANSWER" followed by a text dump, sould be downvoted and closed for the same reasons as any other bad or lazy question.

Comment: _"I don't find it normal that a beginner does not really have the same chance than an experimented developer, as its reputation tends to stay low"_ I started on Stack Overflow with _zero_ programming experience. And trust me, the site and policies have not changed much since then. Do you have anything to help show us that beginners don't have the same chances? (Not to mention that reputation just unlocks extra features.)

Comment: I'm a student and I've asked a lot of good questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Congrats ! I'm so glad for you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers, which includes student programmers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quality is quality, and I don't think students should be *insulted* by lowering the bar for questions. Besides, anyone can ask terrible questions, and meritocracy is implicitly part of the SE model.

Not everyone can be a Jon Skeet - but if you aren't learning to *search* for things, *cite* what you've found, and work towards *clearly* articulate your issues, you aren't learning to feed yourself the knowledge you know.

While the various SE sites *aren't* just for professionals, the higher bar is what keeps it useful and relevant.

I'd also suggest as a student - perhaps being able to *find* and *synthesise* knowledge, is just as important as being given an answer. Asking good questions also helps you think. Spoonfeeding's going to stunt your acedemic growth.

Finally If I understand you correctly

> So I would suggest a scholarship proof from the university or school to avoid derives.

Adds an administrative burden to SE... and I'm sure I could fake admission to an educational institution in about 10 minutes in photoshop.

I've heard a few suggestions that we should start a "learners" version of SO, but you're unlikely to have the best folk answering.

Comment: A proof of scholarship doesn't make the content you post all of a sudden 10% better.

Comment: hah. I didn't have a degree when I was a new SE user. Eventually got one. I don't think I'm any smarter ;p

Comment: @rene I was seeing the proof of scholarship as a "studentship guarantee" rather than a "quality guarantee"

Comment: @MysteryGuy the quality guarantee is all that matter to us. That you're lost and forgotten in an elderly home is of no importance, as long as the content you post is up to par (and don't drool on the keyboard) ....

Comment: drool on the keyboard is between you and the keyboard ;p

Comment: Well, there is the _English Language Learners_ site in addition to _English Language and Usage_, so there is a demand, at least in some areas.