# Comments with MathJax not rendered on Firefox ESR

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, firefox, mathjax

As of today comments do not render MathJax and remaining text. It only flashes the underlying LaTeX, but renders an empty space. Noticed on MSE and MO, [for example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622085/confusion-about-the-definition-of-positive-definiteness) one comment now simply reads: "@Eric Write – Aweygan Jan 26 at 14:08 ".

Have tried different MathJax renderers or other MathJax context menu settings.

The problem appears on Windows 7 32bit and Firefox ESR (with a clean profile too). Works normal on Chrome and the new Firefox Quantum.

UPDATE: Broken on Tor Browser 7.0.2 (based on Firefox 52.2.0). But works on PaleMoon 27.7.1!
Broken on Basilisk web browser.

Comment: ESR is not officially supported.

Comment: There have been patches out earlier today: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503/158100 this can be yet another regression.

Comment: Sonic and @rene - thanks for instant replies. I'm afraid ESR will continue to be widely used for a while and is occasionally updated: mine is 52.6.0.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments to the post [Comment timestamp is not showing in Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/date-time-on-comments), there are two workarounds for now for Firefox ESR 52.6.0.

- Click on "show xx more comments" (if this is present).
- Otherwise, open and close the Web Developer Inspector panel (Cntrl+Shift+C).

<s>Hopefully, these will be needed only temporarily.</s>

---

**Update:** It seems that the patch from almost two years ago is no longer working, or has been deleted. But both of these workarounds still work (tested on ESR 52.9.0 32-bit).

Comment: Both workarounds work! Thank you, Joseph. Works on MO also. Let's wait and see if it gets fixed and then we can close this question.

Comment: **Update:** The developer says he/she hopes to have a quick patch ready tomorrow, [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/comment-timestamp-is-not-showing-in-firefox-esr#comment996487_306503).

Comment: **Update 2**: It seems that the patch from almost two years ago is no longer working, or has been deleted. But both of these two workarounds still work. (Tested on ESR 52.9.0.) This comment was added Dec 12, 2019, which I note here because if you are reading this, you likely cannot see the SE date :(.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine now, see my [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503/115866).

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! And sorry for the nuisance of having to support an older browser.