# Comments not showing time of posting under some circumstances

Tags: bug, comments

Looking at [this comment thread](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/48381/130), I noticed the times for the comments are missing:

[image: screenshot of comment thread]

When I reload the page, I see the times on the comments for a fraction of a second, and then they are gone.  On shorter comment threads, I sometimes do see the comments.  Initially I thought that they seemed to disappear if and only if the comments thread gets collapsed due to a large number of comments.  When I click on "show 14 more comments", all comments are shown, including the times, but for shorter comment threads, I sometimes do, sometimes do not see them all; I cannot fully reproduce this.

[Pale Moon version 28.1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Moon_%28web_browser%29) on Linux (Ubuntu xenial 16.04), no user scripts.

Comment: No repro (on Safari on iOS). Do you have a userscript running? (It could even be one of mine... no way to check right now.)

Comment: @Glorfindel No (edited post with more detail)

Comment: I can reproduce this effect with Firefox 52.9.0 (32 bit), no scripts.

Comment: same here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339756

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comments with MathJax not rendered on Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306506/comments-with-mathjax-not-rendered-on-firefox-esr)

Answer (score 0):

Support for older/obsolete browsers [has been removed recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391888/1038015), specifically browser prefixing.

Firefox 52 was released on September 20, 2016 and Palemoon 28.1.0 on September 20, 2018. They are simply too old, only recent [browser versions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) are supported.

Comment: Could you clarify how this explains the problem being exhibited? Plenty of users browse wih unsupported browsers, but text disappearing after page load is an odd issue to see from simply removing old browser prefixes. Simply saying "they're not supported" isn't particularly helpful, as unsupported browsers aren't always the cause of the problem.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391888/3648282, which links to here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support - which leads to: https://browserl.ist/?q=last+2+versions%2C+not+dead%2C+not+ie+%3E+0%2C+not+op_mini+all%2C+not+baidu+%3E+0%2C+not+and_ff+%3E+0%2C+not+and_qq+%3E+0%2C+not+kaios+%3E+0%2C+not+op_mob+%3E+0%2C+not+ie_mob+%3E+0%2C+not+and_uc+%3E+0%2C+not+Samsung+%3E+0%2C+not+Android+%3E+0 (a specific list) and https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist the GitHub which answers animuson's comment (why?).