# Comments missing timestamp and MathJaX in Firefox ESR 52 (2019)

Tags: bug, comments, firefox, mathjax, timestamps

Similar symptoms to the last year's problem [Comment timestamp is not showing in Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/comment-timestamp-is-not-showing-in-firefox-esr) and [Comments with MathJax not rendered on Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306506/comments-with-mathjax-not-rendered-on-firefox-esr) and same workarounds: Either, open and close the Web Developer Inspector (Cntrl+Shift+C); Or, Restore-Maximize the browser window.

It's an old "unsupported" browser Firefox 52.9 32bit, so if not fixable, I'll keep using the Win+KeyDown & Win+KeyUp combination to re-render the page with corrupted comments. Not every page needs it. I look at the last comments: if they're missing a timestamp, there might be some MathJax missing too.

UPDATE: I was asked to edit the question to address that "Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem". Well, a reiteration that my Firefox is not supported, which I stated already in my question, does not solve my problem. I'm looking to collect workarounds here. Pressing a number of keys to resize the body is one solution, also please take a look at another thread [JavaScript to resize and re-render an element or the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259242/javascript-to-resize-and-re-render-an-element-or-the-window) where I'm asking for an automatic Javascript user-script that would do the workaround for me each time after the page is loaded.

Comment: Similar, and recent: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339715/282094 - workaround: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339715/282094

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comments with MathJax not rendered on Firefox ESR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306506/comments-with-mathjax-not-rendered-on-firefox-esr)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comments not showing time of posting under some circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339715/comments-not-showing-time-of-posting-under-some-circumstances) - See [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339716/282094) instead of question, FF 52 is too old to be on the supported browser list.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE. The problem is explained ("unsupported") but not solved. I'm looking for a nicer automatic solution than pressing keys each time I load a page.