# Make existing timeline icon of a post available to anybody and not only to mods

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, timeline

I noticed that on a site where I'm a moderator, there is a small icon below the up-/downvote buttons and *favorite* icons of every post, which looks like a small clock, and which actually links to the timeline of that post.

Here is a sample of such icon:

[image: Timeline icon]

Some use cases where a timeline benefits my non-diamond moderation activities:

1. Get a **chronological sequence** of:

   - answers to a post.
   - edits (revisions) of a post.
   - a bounty that was started, or ended, as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#history_ced44ed6-62f8-4f1d-bd48-dcfcc85d3b48).
   - review votes (close, reopen, suggested edits, ...).
   - comments.
2. **Events about a post** for which I do not know any other way to discover them:

   - posts that got tweeted, as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#history_8888b1cb-817a-40e7-ad7f-8997f1f53d31).
   - posts that at some point became a hot network question, as in [this example](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/223254/timeline#history_eb995f39-8ff6-4153-b528-9b2e6950a76e).
   - close votes that are invalidated, as in [this example](https://devops.stackexchange.com/posts/226/timeline#review_147).
   - reopen votes that are invalidated as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#review_94495).
   - posts that were deleted and then undeleted again, as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#history_633f3a7e-c7a0-4d56-b7e7-cebd3f464b85).
3. **Notices** that get added to, or removed from, a post, such as:

   - posts that get locked / unlocked, as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#history_28304bae-5040-4156-9005-d9ddc3544676).
   - notices about *Historical significance* of a post,  as in [this example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#history_4e85f203-c2a7-482a-bfc9-7045ec58b726).
4. Track the **history of daily vote totals**, as in [this example](https://devops.stackexchange.com/posts/1898/timeline#voteaggregate_637118783999999999).
5. **Lookup the exact hyperlink** to a specific comment (e.g. to link to it, as in [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/340118/timeline#comment_1136531)), as an alternative to clicking on the timestamp of the comment, and which results in a shorter URL, eg ending with `posts/340118/timeline#comment_1137398`.

So as a followup to [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294584/286501) to "[Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/286501)", and since a timeline is only protected by a "*you name it, you got it*" <sup>(1)</sup>, I suggest to make that timeline icon visible to anybody (not just moderators).

Note: this question in NOT about changing any of the existing timeline privileges, only about improving the existing UI to make an available icon (to mods only for now) visible to anybody. And hence make using it more user friendly, instead of having to know it does exist, and typing in its URL to access it.

<sup>(1):</sup> click the <kbd>edit</kbd> link below a post and then change  `edit` to  `timeline` in the last part of the url.

Comment: Note that the moderator timeline includes many events and additional pieces of information that do not appear in the normal user timeline. Aside from that, the timeline is very much an advanced user feature. If it’s going to be part of the UI, I’d recommend it be tied to moderation privileges so new users aren’t burdened with it.

Comment: There could also be an option in site preferences that shows timeline links, which is off by default. It can also be done with a userscript (which is what I do), but it'd probably be better for it to be a built-in option

Comment: @PierreVriens Note I mention using a question's timeline, to determine things like it being added to the HNQ list or a tweet occurring, in my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340113/562482) to [Is there a way to determine how/why when one of my posts on a network site suddenly starts getting unusual traction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340064/is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-why-when-one-of-my-posts-on-a-network-site-sudde). Also, when I saw this question, I edited my answer to link to it.

Comment: Point four is kinda unnecessary. You can get the URL of a comment by right clicking on the timestamp of the comment. [Tweeting is in the edit history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/105603/revisions), as are post notices.

Comment: @Catija indeed, I rephrased that item to illustrate the difference ...

Comment: This is even more important now that stackexchange again broke their UI for Firefox ESR users and we no longer see time stamps on comments etc. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339756/comments-missing-timestamp-and-mathjax-in-firefox-esr-52-2019)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The public timeline for all questions and answers is now available for all users. More details [are available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/51).

Comment: This is cooooooooool

Comment: This isn't just ***cooooooooool*** ... this is ***formidaaaaaaaaaaaaaable***! Merci Yaakov (and [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)) for accepting and implementing my feature request, +1 and *Accept* of course ... Are you in for my ***next timeline feature request***?

Comment: Thanks to both you and Shog for the work on this feature and getting it out! :)