# Supported browser versions needs updating

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, browsers

In February of this year, I posted a bug report requesting an update for the [Browser support page](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) to list the *current* browser version numbers:
[Supported browser versions needs update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387028/supported-browser-versions-needs-update)

As the answer to that question suggests, in March the latest browser version numbers *were* updated, but they haven't been updated since and once again are significantly out of date:

| Browser | Latest Version (according to the browser support page) | Latest Version (August) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | 110 | 115 |
| Edge | 110 | 115 |
| Firefox | 110 | 116 |
| Opera | 95 | 101 |
| Safari | 16.3 | 16.6 |

---

**Can this be *permanently* fixed?**

- Either, by having the browser version numbers updated periodically — automatically or manually (perhaps only once every few weeks).
- Or, by simply having the version numbers removed from that page altogether; listing the supported browser *names* only.  After all, that page does already say:

  > Stacks supports the last two stable versions of each major browser.

Comment: The chart is also unclear because it talks about the "last two stable versions", but what about ESR releases?

Comment: I still don't understand why this page isn't dynamic... It and the versions shown are completely static, based on whenever the underlying browserslist package was last updated. This leads to competing guidance– _either_ they support the listed versions, _or_ they the support the latest 2. Those *are not compatible definitions* if the page isn't going to be consistently updated. It would be really great if SE would either make the page generation/ deployment automatic & regular on their side, or make the version list on the page dynamic in the first place.

Comment: @Rock officially not supported, however sometimes [even those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503/152859) get fixed anyway.

Comment: @zcoop98 agreed, as a static page it's worthless, and better have FAQ that users here can edit, would be almost surely more up to date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have now automatized the process of updating the browsers versions shown in [browsers.stackoverflow.design](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

Technical details can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/StackExchange/browserslist-viewer/commit/c3cec02cdf09d67f8ec22f4a0916ca84bc0c1434).

Comment: Favicon is missing in Mozilla Firefox browser for the browser version page. Refer the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz6yH.png

Comment: @Arulkumar same with Chrome, showing the default icon. However, might be some generic issue with more sites, e.g. see [this in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9635408#9635408). (TL;DR GitHub also suffer from this problem.)

Comment: We don't have a favicon for that separate web page. I can double check with design  what we should ideally display as a favicon but it is certainly a low priority issue for us.

Comment: I double checked with Design. You should now be able to see the same favicon we use for [stackoverflow.design](https://stackoverflow.design/).

Comment: It's not updating the versions for *all* of the browsers, see [Supported browser versions needs updating for all supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394750/supported-browser-versions-needs-updating-for-all-supported-browsers)

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394751/1264612) is pretty much correct. We are using caniuse data to automatically update browser versions. If something is slightly outdated on their end we are affected. They are generally pretty accurate though.